# Running "Project_Name" with {"rootTag":11}

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

While I debugging react-native my app using (npx react-native run-android) command, After the executing of app is automatically close in my android phone(vivo z1x). I don't know, what is the reason? And I also want to know, What is the meaning of `{"rootTag" : 11}`.

I want to know, What is the meaning of `{"rootTag" : 11}` in react-native.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see your app is closing which means **it's crashing** on start-up.

You can do one thing when app is crashing on startup,
**follow the below steps** to find the reason for the crash.

- Connect you app with system
- open **Android Studio**
- open android directory of you project in Android studio
- You will see **logcat** option in bottom area of Android studio
- open it where you can see the device logs
- open app on android
- now when app closes again, you can see the **Red lines** of output on android studio, which is the reason why your app is getting closed after opening it.

also share the logcat logs on this question, so that anyone can help you with that crash issue.

And your query regarding the rootTag, you can checkout about rootTag on [rootTag](https://reactnative.dev/docs/roottag) which we dont have to deal with in out development. still if you want to know about it you can checkout the link.